# 301 redirect with a directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Following works fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I need to do the same but with a directory, like

www.mydomain.com/oldname/something to www.mydomain.com/NEWNAME/something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the rule that redirects the domain, add these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?oldname/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/newname/$1 [L,R=301]
```